# Need more then two date format routing in web api project

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need support two dates in web api route

[Route("user/{userid:int}/subscriptions/{subscriptionid:int}/timeentries/{fromDate:datetime:regex(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})}/{*toDate:datetime:regex(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})}")]

It will work , or i need to do something else.

Comment: working fine such type of request  https://127.0.0.1:446/api/v2/user/1/subscriptions/1/2012-03-03/2023-03-03

Comment: Finally got its working fine with this request

https://[url]/api/v2/user/1/subscriptions/1/2012-03-03/2023-03-03